# toHtml function is empty issue

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1

This is my code:

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoice_id)
$block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('mynamespace_mymodule/pdf_invoice')
        ->setData('invoice', $invoice)
        ->setTemplate('mynamespace_mymodule/pdf/invoice.phtml');
var_dump($block->toHtml());
```

The result of the var_dump is empty. Smth I am missing. What should I have to check ? thx

This is the xml from layout:

```
<mynamespace_mymodule_pdf_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/pdf_invoice" template ="mynamespace_mymodule/pdf_invoice.phtml" output="toHtml" name="email_invoice_pdf"/>
        </reference>
<mynamespace_mymodule_pdf_index>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common reasons for an empty return value of `toHtml()` are:

- module output is disabled for `Mynamespace_Mymodule` in *System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Module Output*
- the template is behind a symlink and symlinks are not allowed in *System > Configuration > Developer > Template*

**Update:** Having a closer look at your code, you are referencing two different blocks in XML and PHP, `mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_pdf_invoice`/`mynamespace_mymodule/pdf_invoice`. But I don't think that is the problem, because you would get an error message if the block class was missing. Also if you use `createBlock`, nothing has to be defined in the XML.

Comment: P.S.: To better find these kind of errors I built a development extension that might be helpful for you https://github.com/schmengler/DebugErrors

Answer (score 0):

In my case empty string was related to the need to specify template in appropriate block.

For example `"$this->setTemplate('Acidgreen_BlogPage::page/view/list.phtml')"` in block constructor.

Because it was specified in **XML** and it doesn't work when trying to get html with ajax.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
$layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
/** @var \Acidgreen\BlogPage\Block\Post\PostList\Posts $block */
$block = $layout->createBlock(\Acidgreen\BlogPage\Block\Post\PostList\Posts::class);

/** @var array $response */
$response = [
    'content' => $block->toHtml(),
];
```