# Block does not loading in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, blocks, template

Module creates custom page on admin panel, page loads as an empty page.
By debugging I've seen that corresponding action is loaded, but for some reason it doesn't load template file, also as I could see JS and CSS links are correctly added to header.
here part from layout:

```
<modulname_adminhtml_controllername_actionname>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>customjs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</file></action>
        <action method="addCss"><file>../../../../js/customjs/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css</file></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="namespacename_modulename/adminhtml_actionname" name="modulename" />
    </reference>
</modulname_adminhtml_controllername_actionname>
```

Magento Version 1.8.1.0

Action:

```
public function actionnameAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('namespacename_modulename/cotrollername');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Is there something which need to be fixed?

Comment: `modulname_adminhtml_controllername_actionname`   and  `connector_adminhtml_connectordebug_syncheader` both should be same

Comment: Can you add your block code?

Comment: @tjons what part exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Module Output were **DISABLED** I've found solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116861/tohtml-function-is-empty-issue/116870#116870).

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at your layout file, it looks like you haven't specified a template for the block. Use the `template` attribute:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="namespacename_modulename/adminhtml_actionname" name="modulename" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Also, as @Same pointed out, the handle nodes should be the same...

Comment: Nodes are same, it was wrongly written in question, which I've just fixed.
About the template="path/to/your/template.phtml" I've tested also with that version, it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you change it the template path and clear caches?

Comment: template="my_module_dir_in_adminhtml/mytemplate.phtml"   is this enough or I have to add something else? caches I'm cleaning after each code update.